# Display error from nested array using ngIf

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-ng-if

I have following HTML

```
<div formArrayName="reservation_and_confirmation" *ngFor="let _reservation_and_confirmation of form.get('reservation_and_confirmation').controls; let i = index;" class="row">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h4>
            {{ 'reservation_and_confirmation' | translate }} {{ 0 == i ? '' : '-' }} {{ 0 == i ? '' : i }}
        </h4>
        <a class="add-button pull-right" href="#" (click)="updateMultiInputField('reservation_and_confirmation', i)">
            <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-{{0 == i ? 'plus' : 'minus'}}"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div (domChange)="onInputClone('reservation_and_confirmation', i, $event)" class="form-horizontal main-content">
        <span [formGroupName]="i">
            <div class="form-group main-form-block">
                <label for="venue-type" class="col-sm-6 control-label">{{ 'contact_person' | translate }} *</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6 form-input">
                    <input formControlName="name" type="text" class="form-control">
                    <ng-container *ngFor="let errorMessage of errors.reservation_and_confirmation; let _i = index">
                        <span class="error-msg" *ngIf="_i == i && errorMessage.name">{{errorMessage.name}}</span>
                    </ng-container>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group main-form-block">
                <label for="venue-type" class="col-sm-6 control-label">{{ 'title' | translate }} *</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6 form-input">
                    <select formControlName="title" class="selectpicker" title="{{ 'select' | translate }}" id="venue-type">
                        <option value="mr">Mr.</option>
                        <option value="mrs">Mrs.</option>
                        <option value="ms">Ms.</option>
                        <option value="dr">Dr.</option>
                        <option value="prof">Prof.</option>
                    </select>
                    <ng-container *ngFor="let errorMessage of errors.reservation_and_confirmation; let _i = index">
                        <span class="error-msg" *ngIf="_i == i && errorMessage.title">{{errorMessage.title}}</span>
                    </ng-container>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group main-form-block">
                <label for="venue-type" class="col-sm-6 control-label">{{ 'position' | translate }} *</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6 form-input">
                    <input formControlName="designation"  type="text" class="form-control">
                    <ng-container *ngFor="let errorMessage of errors.reservation_and_confirmation; let _i = index">
                        <span class="error-msg" *ngIf="_i == i && errorMessage.designation">{{errorMessage.designation}}</span>
                    </ng-container>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group main-form-block">
                <label for="venue-type" class="col-sm-6 control-label">{{ 'work_email' | translate }} *</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6 form-input">
                    <input formControlName="email"  type="text" class="form-control">
                    <ng-container *ngFor="let errorMessage of errors.reservation_and_confirmation; let _i = index">
                        <span class="error-msg" *ngIf="_i == i && errorMessage.email">{{errorMessage.email}}</span>
                    </ng-container>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group main-form-block">
                <label for="venue-type" class="col-sm-6 control-label">{{ 'phone_number' | translate }} *</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6 form-input">
                    <input formControlName="phone_number" type="text" class="form-control phonepicker">
                    <ng-container *ngFor="let errorMessage of errors.reservation_and_confirmation; let _i = index">
                        <span class="error-msg" *ngIf="_i == i && errorMessage.phone_number">{{errorMessage.phone_number}}</span>
                    </ng-container>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group main-form-block">
                <label for="venue-type" class="col-sm-6 control-label">{{ 'fax_number' | translate }} *</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6 form-input">
                    <input formControlName="fax_number" type="text" class="form-control phonepicker">
                    <ng-container *ngFor="let errorMessage of errors.reservation_and_confirmation; let _i = index">
                        <span class="error-msg" *ngIf="_i == i && errorMessage.fax_number">{{errorMessage.fax_number}}</span>
                    </ng-container>
                </div>
            </div>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to display errors in corresponding field, as you can see I am using `FormArray` to loop and clone the elements.

Here is the example error message I receive from the server.

```
{  
   "status":"error",
   "message":"Please fix the error and resubmit the form.",
   "errors":{  
      "reservation_and_confirmation":[  
         {  
            "designation":"This value is required",
            "email":"This value is required",
            "phone_number":"This value is required",
            "fax_number":"This value is required"
         },
         {  
            "title":"This value is required",
            "designation":"This value is required",
            "email":"This value is required",
            "phone_number":"This value is required",
            "fax_number":"This value is required"
         }
      ],
      "special_order_information":[  
         {  
            "name":"This value is required",
            "title":"This value is required",
            "designation":"This value is required",
            "email":"This value is required",
            "phone_number":"This value is required",
            "fax_number":"This value is required"
         }
      ],
      "accounting_department_authorised_contact":[  
         {  
            "name":"This value is required",
            "title":"This value is required",
            "designation":"This value is required",
            "email":"This value is required",
            "phone_number":"This value is required",
            "fax_number":"This value is required"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I want to display the error message based on Index, here is how I am doing it.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let errorMessage of errors.reservation_and_confirmation; let _i = index">
    <span class="error-msg" *ngIf="_i == i && errorMessage.name">{{errorMessage.name}}</span>
</ng-container>
```

This works when the error messages has indexes starting from 0 (indexes in 
 error messages is mapped to FormArray element index), in some cases for example if first `FormArray` element has no error, the first index is 1, in this case it throws the error.

How can I display the error message using ngIf with correct indexes.

Thanks.

Comment: Use: *ngIf="_i == i && errorMessage?.name" (the safe operator) https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#safe-navigation-operator

Comment: @Eliseo It works if errorMessages has indexes starting from 0, now if first FormArray will have no errors, then the error message index will start with 1, this is when it throws the error.

Comment: If you don't have,e.g a null, -I supouse some like  "reservation and confirmation":[ null, {"designation":"This value is required"}].. I don't imagine how you can know the incorrect line :(

Comment: Okay, the thing is, it is trying to access corresponding error element using the index, whereas the error does not exist for given FormArray if it has no error. the current work around is I am returning an empty array if it has no errors this way it works. However I am still looking to put a condition to show and display error message from specific index of error messages object.